# Having a problem in reading an Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, office-interop

my project is open excel file and read row by row  in C# but my excel reference file exist some empty row

for example first and second row is't empty (no cells) but all cells of Third, fourth and fifth row is

empty and then cells of  next row is not empty etc. now when my code is in running in the for just Reads

only the  first few rows of the file that are full  And as soon as reach the first row completely empty

It comes out of the loop While reading the file is not over yet. why this occur ?how can fixed it ?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           
            Excel.Application xlApp;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            Excel.Range range;

            string str;
            string table = null;
            int rCnt;
            int cCnt;
            int rw = 0;
            int cl = 0;

            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\mostafaheydarsana\Desktop\mp.xlsx", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
            rw = range.Rows.Count;
            cl = range.Columns.Count;
           
            string s = "'nbn";
            
            string table_row = null;

            int io = 0;
            
            string new_str = null;
            
            string question_field = null;
            
            int peymaeshrowaforaddquestioha;

            try
            {
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\Test.txt");

                for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= rw; rCnt++)
                {
                    
                    if (range.Cells[rCnt, 1].Value != null)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("question is ( " + question_field + s[0] + "," + new_str + "');", io++);
                        
                        MessageBox.Show("rCnt is " + rCnt + "quesstion_field is insert in file ***" + question_field + "***");

                        question_field = null;
                       
                        new_str = null;

                        new_str += s[0] + range.Cells[rCnt, 1].Value2.ToString() + s[0] + "," + s[0] + range.Cells[rCnt, 2].Value2.ToString() + s[0] + "," + s[0] + range.Cells[rCnt, 3].Value2.ToString() + s[0];

                        question_field += range.Cells[rCnt, 4].Value2.ToString();

                    }
                    else if(range.Cells[rCnt, 1].Value == null)
                    {

                        question_field += range.Cells[rCnt, 4].Value2.ToString();

                        MessageBox.Show("rCnt is " + rCnt + "quesstion_field is ***" + question_field + "***");

                        peymaeshrowaforaddquestioha = rCnt + 1;

                    }
                }
                
                sw.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ec)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ec.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
            }

            xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
            
            xlApp.Quit();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);


        }
```

Comment: Well, IF a row is completely “empty”, then when you get to the if statement… `if (range.Cells[rCnt, 1].Value != null)…` then this will be `false` because all the cells on that row are null. Therefore, the `else` portion will execute… `else if(range.Cells[rCnt, 1].Value == null)` … this will be `true` and execute the next line of code… `question_field += range.Cells[rCnt, 4].Value2.ToString();` … which will throw a `null` exception since `range.Cells[rCnt, 4].Value2` will be `null.` Are you not seeing the output of this exception in the `catch` portion?

Comment: @mostafa, is your problem solved? Please check if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a lot with the MS OpenXML libraries to create Excel output, I discovered the ClosedXML package in NuGet, which turned out a much better and easier method.  It may well be possible to also solve your problem of reading Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, the problem is that you will get the exception 'Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference' when you try to access the null cells.

According the reference [Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference - Empty Excel Cells](http://Cannot%20perform%20runtime%20binding%20on%20a%20null%20reference%20-%20Empty%20Excel%20Cells), you can try to modify the following code.

Change

```
 question_field += range.Cells[rCnt, 4].Value2.ToString();
```

Into:

```
  question_field +=Convert.ToString(range.Cells[rCnt, 4].Value2);
```

It works for me.